# Does "before Dec 10 midnight" mean "before Dec 09 - 23:59" or "before Dec 10 - 23:59"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, time, logic

When a deadline says, submit "before Dec 10 midnight". Does it mean "before Dec 09 - 23:59" or "before Dec 10 - 23:59"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These questions about English dates and times come up very often.  Unfortunately, unless the sentence specifies an exact date and time, the correct answer is always going to be, "You have to ask to be sure."

Technically, yes, *midnight December 10* is one second after 23:59:59 on December 9th.  However, in practice most people consider the day to "end" when they go to sleep.  If they are up at midnight, it's still the same day as when they first awoke.

So therefore, I would assume your example means "*by 23:59 on December 10, plus one minute*" -- but, if it's important, I would ask for clarification.

Of course, if you can turn in your work by *23:59 on December 9*, it's a moot point, since you've beaten the deadline either way.

Answer (score 1):

The day usually starts at midnight, so "before Dec 10 midnight" usually is the same as "before Dec 10".
"Before Dec 09 - 23:59:59" excludes one second.

But people using such deadlines may see this differently.

So maybe write "valid through Dec 9" or include "23:59" to make it clear.

See also:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight